# Ubuntu 10.10 theme changed after driver install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

After installing the nvidia drivers and rebooting my theme changed to an ugly gray theme. Changing the theme in the System>Preferences>Appearance only changes the window title bars but everything else stays in this ugly gray theme.

The drivers are installed and working (visual effects work).

I also updated everything from the Update Manager before rebooting.
Also this is a brand new install. Only changes are from the Update Manager and the Driver utility.
Every thing looked fine before I rebooted (default ubuntu 10.10 theme)

How can I get rid of the this gray theme?

Also I am new to ubuntu, mainly use GUIs to set things up. I'm not afraid of the terminal, but I just don't know my way around the Linux file system yet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this happening only with certain applications or all? Also, did you try to change the controls-theme directly via the customize option?

Comment: All windows have this problem.  I have selected the default theme "ambiance" from the appearance preferences.  Also windows will return the correct theme when I log out and log back in sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. There is a fix for it [documented on the ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10428836&postcount=6).

> Go to `System > Administration >
>   Additional Drivers`
>
> It shows a graphics driver that was
>   not activated.
>
> > ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics
> >     driver Tested by the Ubuntu developers
> >     License: Proprietary 3D-accelerated
> >     proprietary graphics driver for ATI
> >     cards.
>
> This driver is required to fully
>   utilise the 3D potential of some ATI
>   graphics cards, as well as provide 2D
>   acceleration of newer cards.
>
> I clicked to activate it and it told
>   me to restart. I restarted and
>   everything worked correctly.